# Fetch the products URL

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I have following link which gives the product list.
But I am unable to fetch these product in PHP array how to fetch these product.
please give me some idea.

URL- https://www.rudolphs-christmasshop.com.au/api/v2/products/

Comment: Data in xml format. How did you try to fetch it?

Comment: Give us a paste of the data or the login details for that page. Without either of them no one can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to get XML from a URL - perhaps the simplest is using [`simplexml_load_file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) :

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
print_r($xml);
```

Where obviously `$url` is your URL. You can add the username and password into the URL like `http://username:password@url/`

Or you could use [cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) and then [simplexml_load_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) to parse the results:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ':' . $password);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($result);
```